# Has Magento a fallback for default email templates?

Tags: magento, email

Hi I have created an module with a custom transactional email, which works fine when i place the default-template-file in

```
app/locale/de_DE/template/email/sales/mymail.html
```

but i need to place it into my template

```
app/design/frontend/ultimo/custom/locale/de_DE/templete/email/sales/mymail.html
```

but on this path it isn't found, i even tried otherplaces like

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/locale/de_DE/templete/email/sales/mymail.html
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/de_DE/templete/email/sales/mymail.html
```

but neither works. Isn't there any fallback mechanism for these file? If yes, can anyone explain it to me?

Thanks

Comment: Spelling of template is wrong. Also is there a specific reason why you're trying this ? You can always use the app/locale folder itself.

Comment: thanks for the hint, i wanted to create one for each template, but it seems that magento does not support templating fallback for this, even with correct spelling